# How to add data on a Push Key from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to `firebase` and have been struggling the past days on something probably very simple.

Users are able to post. On top of that, they are also able to comment on posts. I would like to save each comment to their specific post that they have commented on.

> Please check the below image for clarification.

[RED: what I am trying to add in userPost's Push Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i96gA.png)

How can i access the `userPost's Push Key` to basically push more data in?
I am working with **JavaScript (ES6/React)** and would be grateful for any help or tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the users can comment on a post in a screen where you display that post. In that case, you'll need to store the key of the post somewhere in that screen, and then use it to post the comment to the database.

The actual posting of the comment will look something like this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("userPosts").ref(postId);
ref.child("comments").push("comment on post");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. If I understood this correctly, referring to your example, I first need to get the userPost's Push Key with the following for example: .push().getKey() and then set it to "postId" ?

Comment: You will need to *know* the key of the post you're trying to update. Usually you'd do that by keeping it somewhere in the HTML, when you render the post.